# How to write a shell script to check the mysql database backup status.

Tags: mysql, backup, linux

I have mysql production databases running in main server(Linux) and from this server every night the backup is taken into local server. 
Now i want to find a shell script to check if all the databases backup is up to date or not(for an example: i have twenty database in the main server so i want to know all of them have been backed up completely or not) and compare the each database's current size with their previous size, in a sense i want to make sure with through this script that my backup is perfect and if not i will have a track of that occurrence.

Please help me to get a solution of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This would indeed be nice to be able to do it in an automatic way. Unfortunately, to be 100% sure your backups are fine, you need human intervention. After taking the backup, you must be able to check if you can import it safely. Of course, you can not always do it. You can check your backups for example every 2-4 days.

On the other hand, you can always check if the size of the new backup is significantly smaller than the previous one (considering that the database always increases in size). This could be an indication that your backup might not have been taken correctly or is corrupted.

Comment: Why would you say that performing an automated restore with sanity checks require human intervention?  This can be scripted.

Comment: I was looking for the script to check the backup automatically. So if i am unable to check the backup for few day's their will be history or alert log that will inform me that, from all of my databases individual or total servers backup was interrupted.

Comment: @Aaron Brown Yes please!  I'm a MS SQL Server DBA and figuring out automation on Postgres/MySQL has been a challenge.  If you could provide a framework to start that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite difficult problem, you can get quite close by checking the backup size difference and use various [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) algorithms to decide if there is something wrong or not.

The problem is that for example a simple `drop column` will create an anomaly, and then you will start getting a lot of false alerts, which will make you start ignoring the alerts, and when the broken backups actually appear they will be ignored :)

I wrote a [blogpost](https://www.elefantos.com/blog/simple-complexity) investigating backups as a graceful degradation strategy, that discusses similar subject, not sure if it will be helpful to you, but I think it might be.

The way I would approach this is by setting realistic thresholds and alerts, for example start with: "the data will never be 40% smaller than yesterday" or "there will never be less than 1_000_000 products" and start from there. It is key to make sure the false positives are reduced as much as possible.

You should never perform automatic restore, always alert and escalate, otherwise you risk getting subtle corruption of your whole system.

The authoritative data is in many cases used into materialized views with variable time-to-live, so when you restore automatically you risk breakage on undefined places in your data pipeline.

so:

- alert when there are no backups
- alert when backups are *really* bad (40% of size, 30% less products etc)

You can also insert "trusted" records in your main tables, and make sure they are backed up.

For example, insert heartbeat like record, before you do the backup, then check if the backup contains it (which you can check by re-applying the backup on empty database and actually looking at the number of rows after the heartbeat)